# Stack smashing detected. What it means and how can I fix it?

Tags: c

The only elements in the array that I want are the ones that im transforming into 1, but for some reason the when im navigating trough the lower part this stack smashing occur.

````
```
#include <stdio.h>
#define tam 12

int main(void) {
  int i, j;
  int matriz[tam][tam]={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
  int controle = 0, controle2 = 0;

  for(i = 0; i<6;i++){
    for(j=i;j<tam-i;j++){
      matriz[tam-(i)][tam-(j+1)]=1;
      matriz[i-1][j]=1;
    }
  }
  for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
    for(j=0;j<tam;j++){
      printf("%i ", matriz[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```
`
```
````

Comment: Are you sure your array lookups are always in the correct range 0..11? `i-1` seems bad when `i=0`.

Comment: that's what stack smashing means? If so, I have to confirm.

Comment: It means you started bashing around with memory you're not supposed to touch, in this case the stack itself.

Comment: the stack smashing occur when this line is executed matriz[tam-(i)][tam-(j+1)]=1;

Comment: For what values of `i`, and `j` From there I think you'll come to understand how you're out of bounds.

Comment: `i = 0` What happens in `matriz[i-1][j]=1;`??

Answer (score 2):

`matriz[tam-i]` will resolve to `matriz[12]` when `i = 0`. This is the out of bounds write, and the source of the bug

Comment: There's a few others, like `matriz[0-1][0]=1` on the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the `for(i = 0; i<6;i++)` to `for(i = 1; i<6;i++)` should work, if that's the result you're trying to hv